# How to stabilize NN-model for timeseries prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm new to Machine Learning and Neural Nets and am experimenting with a configuration I found in a [blog post](https://iq.opengenus.org/time-series-prediction-techniques/). I try to build a model to predict the value 4 time steps ahead of the last value fed to the model as a feature (window-size is flexibel). E.g. I give the model weeks 1-5 and want to get a prediction for week 9.

Currently I run into the challenge that the model is quite unstable. With this I mean that the predictions differ quite a lot if repeating the steps of data preparation, building a dataset, building and training the model and finally doing the forecasting.

Sometimes the forecast seems to fit quite nice, sometimes it seems to be inverted via a negativ sign and sometimes just the amplitude doesn't match while the directions are right (see the following screenshots).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I thought that might has to something with the shuffling and size of shuffle_buffer, but this also happens for different sizes of shuffle_buffer, e.g. 20.

[image]
[image]

What is the reason for this behaviour and how to prevent this?

The code:

```
#%% Initializing
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras

#%% Defining the series
series = np.array([ 218,  555,  550,  563, 2492, 2848, 4041, 1302, 1040, 1073, 1392, 2093,
 1870, 2328, 2102, 2844, 1730, 2431, 1974, 2450, 1975, 1415, 2568, 2831,
 3011, 2576, 2825, 3327, 3539, 3392, 2949, 3283, 3854, 3918, 2639, 3826,
 3980, 3134, 3997, 2708, 3257, 3435, 3337, 2571, 3370, 4277, 3482, 2804,
 3253, 2979, 2458, 2306, 2482, 3209, 3915, 1292,  931, 2748, 2874, 2089,
 2660, 3205, 3093, 1389,  834, 1914, 2568, 2831, 2129, 3138, 2841, 2318,
 2653, 1598, 1779, 1529, 2190, 2180, 1737, 1845, 2511, 1922, 3679, 3277,
 2633, 2064, 2802, 2853, 2220, 1987, 2491, 1867, 3593, 1998, 2425, 3226,
 2143, 3466, 3327, 3283, 3011, 2552, 2844, 2501, 1575, 1829, 3086, 3345,
 1905, 1192, 2772, 3667, 4223, 4117, 2113, 2312, 2615, 3126, 2581, 3265,
 3682, 3355, 1820, 2989, 2806, 3333, 2395, 2777, 2189, 2628, 2379, 1867])


time = range(1, len(series)+1)

#%% Prepare Data for NN 
def windowed_dataset(series, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
  dataset = dataset.window(window_size + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
  dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size + 1))
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer).map(lambda window: (window[:-4], window[-1])) # :-4 because we want to predict the value in 4 weeks, not for the next week
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
  return dataset

split_time = len(time)-16
time_train = time[:split_time]
x_train = series[:split_time]

# For normalization based on training data, so that model does not "see" the validation data before validation
train_mean = x_train.mean()
train_std = x_train.std()

x_train_norm = (x_train - train_mean) / train_std
series_norm = (series - train_mean) / train_std


time_valid = time[split_time:]
x_valid = series[split_time:]


def plot_series(time, series, format="-", start=0, end=None):
    plt.plot(time[start:end], series[start:end], format)
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("Value")
    plt.grid(True)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plot_series(time_train, x_train)
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plot_series(time_valid, x_valid)
plt.show()

#%% Build the dataset
w_size = 4
b_size = 4
sb_size = 1
w_size_adjusted = w_size - 3

dataset = windowed_dataset(series_norm, window_size = w_size, batch_size = b_size, shuffle_buffer = sb_size)

#%% Build and train the model


l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[w_size_adjusted])
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([l0])

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-6, momentum=0.9)) # original: learning_rat = 1e-6, also trid [... ].optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-6)
model.fit(dataset,epochs=100,verbose=0)

#%% Forecast data
forecast = []

for time_step in range(len(series) - w_size_adjusted +1):
  forecast.append(model.predict(series_norm[time_step:time_step + w_size_adjusted][np.newaxis]))

forecast_subset = forecast[split_time - w_size_adjusted + 1:]
results_norm = np.array(forecast_subset)[:, 0, 0]

#%% Unnormalize

results = (results_norm * train_std)+train_mean


#%% Plot

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

plot_series(time_valid, x_valid)
plot_series(time_valid, results)
plt.title('window_size: {0}, batch_size: {1}, shuffle_buffer: {2}'.format(w_size, b_size, sb_size))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this does the trick

```
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[w_size_adjusted], kernel_initializer="ones")
```

Essentially, initial weight values make too much of an impact because of too few training data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I identify the impact of the initial weight values? Is there some metric to pull or how would I know that their impact is too big or I have too few training data? Also, with setting  `kernel_initializer="ones"`, the model seems to predict really accurate. Is this actually legit or do I have some flaws in my process which causes overfitting/learning the predictions?

Comment: The rule of thumb for weights is that the number of data points >> number of weights. Setting it to ones removes randomness in the parameter initialisation. I guess the best way to track it is train several models with different random seeds and check the the histogram of model metrics or losses is nice and localised.

Comment: Just to be sure: You ment setting the seed x with `tf.random.set_seed(x)`? I did not find an option to set a seed for the kernel/Dense-Layer specifically.

Comment: yup, that's the one

Comment: The seed literally has no effect on the RMSE or MAPE of the results. I also looped through different combinations of window_size, batch_sitze and shuffle_buffer. The results seem odd. Shuffle_buffer has no impact on RMSE and MAPE. What really has an effect is the window_size. The larger the window_size, the bigger the RMSE and MAPE. The batch_size also as an effect, but smaller. For window_size = 4 the metrics are better for bigger batch_sizes. For all other window_sizes MAPE and RMSE get bigger as batch_size increases. Should I open a new discussion for that or could this be legit bahaviour?

Comment: Effect of the batch size increase is somewhat expected, seen that in other problems. This means that the minimum is narrow, while big batch sizes prefer wider maxima. I think it would be a good idea to open new discussion with perhaps more data example, maybe in external repo if it is too large.

Comment: Also, since there is no randomness in kernel initialisation, seed should have no effect. It will for a default initialisation you might use in a different model.